# JS | Array doesn't save data from the input | solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, this

Ok, there is one problem. The array doesn't save data from the input. When I want to save a name, it still apears empty and I can't output anything. I only test one input for the name to be sure that everything works, before I write a code for other inputs. Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#newContact').on('click', function() {
       $('#dataSection').slideToggle();
       $('#buttonSave').delay(400).fadeToggle();
   });
});


var contacts = [];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName);
};

var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;

function addFirstName(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
};

function saveContact() {
    contacts[contacts.length] = new addFirstName(document.getElementById("firstName").value);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = contacts[0];
};
```

```css
.input-group {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}

#newContact:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#dataSection, #buttonSave {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AddressBookApp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="addressbook.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
       <h2>AddressBook App</h2>
        
        <hr class="my-4">
        
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="newContact">New contact</span></h5>
        
        <!-- Contact section -->
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="dataSection">
            
            <!-- Firstname Input -->
            
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">1</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a first name" aria-label="Name" id="firstName">
            </div>
            
            <!-- LastName Input -->
            
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">2</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a last name" aria-label="Lastname" id="lastName">
            </div>
            
            <!-- PhoneNumber Input -->
            
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">3</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a number phone" aria-label="Number" id="phoneNumber">
            </div>
            
            <!-- Email Input -->
            
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon4">4</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type an email">
            </div>
            </div>
        
        <!-- Button save provided contact -->
        <button onclick="saveContact()" type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="buttonSave">Save</button>
        
        <p id="output"></p>
    </div>

        
        
                
        <!-- Scripts -->
                
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="addressbook.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `contacts[0]` is an object, you have to access it's properties `contacts[0].firstName`

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
function addFirstName(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.getValue = function() {
      return this.firstName;
    }
};

function saveContact() {
    contacts.push(new addFirstName(document.getElementById("firstName").value));
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = contacts[0].getValue();
};
```

The problem was in `addFirstName` instantiating. You put the input value into the property (`firstName`). So you need to access it in some way, e.g. `contacts[0].firstName`. Or via some getter method, which is more generic variant, so you will be able to build some general handlers in future:

```
contacts.forEach(contact => console.log(contact.getValue()))
```

Comment: Isn't that version simpler: `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = contacts[0].firstName` ?

Comment: This depends on your needs, if you want classes then do methods etc, in other way there may be enough just `contacts.push(document.getElementById("firstName").value);` and then `contacts[0]`

Comment: You're right. I am having this trouble now, when updating other input..

Answer (score 0):

```
var contacts = [];

function saveContact() {
    contacts[contacts.length] = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = contacts[0];
};
```

I'm unsure why you do all that new business and what have you, I would just simplify it like this. The way you were doing it before was pushing a new object with the value 'firstName' within it.

Assuming you want to store multiple firstNames in your example, and each object show be essentially a 'contact item' maybe this will make more sense.

```
var contacts = [];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName);
}; 

// I put lastName here as an example of adding other properties to it.
function Contact(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};

function saveContact() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    contacts.push(new Contact(firstName));
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = contacts[0].firstName;
};
```

Comment: But with array I can then make a search option, and type whatever name I want to find, and with just string it's not possible.

Comment: If that's the case, I can give this example a slight tweak.